# Multi-tenant Authentication

Tags: authentication, meteor, multi-tenant

I am just starting out with Meteor coming from Django. I am trying to develop an app that allows for multiple organizations, which have multiple users. The users don't all have email addresses, so I'm using username authentication.

Right now, I'm storing the user's organizationId in Meteor.user().profile, but there's one small issue: there could be a John Smith in multiple organizations, all wanting the same username: jsmith.

I had initially thought about asking them to use something like: jsmith.organization for every user, but that doesn't seem like a good solution, since many of these organizations expect to use the same username everywhere.

In Django, I accomplished this by using a custom authentication backend and adding an Organization Code field to the login page just above the username and password fields. Is there something similar (or better) that I could do with Meteor?

Thanks

Comment: do organizations have unique urls? e.g. www.example.com/organizationx

Comment: @MrD: no, but that could be a possibility, especially if that would make it easier to accomplish this.

Comment: I can think of one way to do it where you could append the organization to the user name without them ever knowing or needing to know. Would that work?

Comment: @MrD: that might work. So long as when they login, they don't have to manually append the organization to their username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrD suggests, transparently adding the organization to the username is a simple way to resolve this issue.

You would probably have a dedicated signin URL for each organization, so you'll know which org to use.  You could also have a global login where users also select an organization.

Check out the `accounts-entry` package for an example of manually calling the authentication methods that the core `accounts-ui` package normally does for you:
https://github.com/BeDifferential/accounts-entry

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, only I added a field for organization above username. I already created my own custom login dropdown, so this was trivial. I then just had it concatenate the username and organization code. I also added a transform to Meteor.users so that it would strip the org code off the username for display in user management sections.